# Swift 3 Paypal Payment not processed

Tags: ios, swift, paypal

Swift 2 Paypal demo

https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/tree/master/SampleApp-Swift/PayPal-iOS-SDK-Sample-App

```
if (payment.processable) 
{
  let paymentViewController = PayPalPaymentViewController(payment: payment,    configuration: payPalConfig, delegate: self)
  present(paymentViewController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

else 
{

   print("Payment not processalbe: \(payment)")
}
```

Swift 3  change

```
    if (payment?.processable)!
    {
        let paymentViewController = PayPalPaymentViewController(payment: payment, configuration: payPalConfig, delegate: self)
        present(paymentViewController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }      
   else
    {
      print("Payment not processalbe: \(payment)")
    }
```

swift 3 Response is

```
  PayPal SDK: PayPalPayment not processable: if paymentDetails are provided, then subtotal must be positive.
Payment not processalbe: Optional(

   CurrencyCode: USD
   Amount: 8.49
   Short Description: Hipster Clothing
   Intent: sale
   Processable: No
   Display: $8.49
   Confirmation: (null)
   Details: Subtotal: 0, Shipping: 5.99, Tax: 2.5
   Shipping Address: (null)
   Invoice Number: (null)
   Custom: (null)
   Soft Descriptor: (null)
   BN code: (null)
   Item: 'Optional({2|Old jeans with holes|84.99|USD|Hip-0037})'
   Item: 'Optional({1|Free rainbow patch|0.00|USD|Hip-00066})'
   Item: 'Optional({1|Long-sleeve plaid shirt (mustache not   included)|37.99|USD|Hip-00291})')



if (payment.processable)
```

It is working fine in swift 2 but I change to code as per swift 3

```
if (payment?.processable)!
```

If I use this as per swift 3 than response is above what do some more changes for swift3.

Comment: even i got same problem, have you found any solution